# Fixed column table with scrollable body not rendering properly in IE 9 & 10

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table I created that has the first two columns "fixed" in place while the body can scroll horizontally. I accomplished this by using two tables, one for the fixed columns and one for the rest of the content. I am using some jQuery to keep the row heights the same across the two tables, but I am running into some issues in IE 9 & 10 where the row heights don't seem to be quite matching up.

This is a slightly truncated version of my table HTML:

```
<div style="width: auto" class="groupDetails">
<table id="table1" class="table1" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <th class="placeHolder" colspan="2">
            &nbsp;
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="shared">
            <td class="groupName">TEST CUSTOMER 1:</td>
            <td class="typeName">First</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="shared">
            <td class="typeName" colspan="2">Second</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="shared totals">
            <td class="typeName" colspan="2">Total for Top:</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="table2">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" id="table2">
        <thead>
            <tr class="subHeader">
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Y</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Y</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Y</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr class="totals">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Y</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Y</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the jQuery I'm using is:

```
$("div.groupDetails").find(".table1 > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var originalIndex = $(this).index();
    $("div.groupDetails").find(".table2 tbody tr").eq(originalIndex)
        .height($(this).height());
});
```

I created a Fiddle to show what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/4HXbz/2/. I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a while now, so any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added `line-height: 1.1em` on your `table > tbody > tr > td` selector to match the font-size which brought the first set of rows into line in ie10, but I couldn't immediately spot the difference about the lower rows which were still problematic... hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks! That set me in the right direction and by changing the padding value of that same selector to "2px 0", it seems to be working fine in IE now. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

[Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat):

@Ross wrote:

> I added `line-height: 1.1em` on your `table > tbody > tr > td` selector to match the font-size which brought the first set of rows into line in ie10, but I couldn't immediately spot the difference about the lower rows which were still problematic... hope this points you in the right direction!

@OP wrote:

> That set me in the right direction and by changing the padding value of that same selector to "2px 0", it seems to be working fine in IE now.